# Unable to change the width of material ui snackbar

Tags: material-ui

When I try to set long text to the snackbar, the action name displayed out of snackbar. I tried setting height with constant figure and minWidth and maxWidth as specified in the code snippet below but not working.

screenshot:

[image]

```
<Snackbar
        open={this.state.open}
        message={this.state.error}
        autoHideDuration={4000}
        bodyStyle={bodyStyle}
        action="Close"
        onRequestClose={this.handleRequestClose}
        onActionTouchTap={this.handleRequestClose}
        style={snackbarfromTop}
      />

   bodyStyle:{
  border: "2px solid #ffffff",
  minWidth: '50%',
  maxWidth: '100%',
  flexGrow: 0,
  height:'55px',
  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  fontFamily: "Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,Lucida Grande,sans-serif",
  fontStyle: 'normal',
  fontWeight: 400,
  fontSize: 16
}

snackbarfromTop: {
  top: 0,
  color: white,
  bottom: 'auto',
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try like this:

```
<Snackbar ContentProps=
{{
   sx:{
       All the styles like (color , backgrndclr) include here
}
}}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?